# solving system of ODEs in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I am using the DSolve to solve the following 2 ODEs
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
&\dot{y}(t)=z(t)-y(t)-\frac{c_1c_2y(t)}{-c_1c_2e^{-t}t+c_1(1-c_2)+c_3e^{-t}}\\
&\dot{z}(t)=-z(t)+\frac{c_1c_2y(t)}{-c_1c_2e^{-t}t+c_1(1-c_2)+c_3e^{-t}}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
with initial value $z(0)=0$ and $y(0)\in(0,1)$.

Then I use the following code

```
system = {y'[t] == -y[t] + z[t] - 
     c1*c2*y[t]/(c1*(1 - c2) - c1*c2*Exp[-t]*t + c3*Exp[-t]), 
   z'[t] == -z[t] + 
     c1*c2*y[t]/(c1*(1 - c2) - c1*c2*Exp[-t]*t + c3*Exp[-t]), 
   z[0] == 0};
```

and

```
DSolve[system, {y[t], z[t]}, t]
```

However, Mathematica did nothing but beautify my input. So does this mean, Mathematica cannot solve this ODE in closed-form?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Yeah, it probably means `DSolve` doesn't know how to solve it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 then is there any more powerful tool to solve ODE symbolically?

Comment: No, I don't think there is.  Sometimes one can apply a change of variables that converts the system to a form `DSolve` can recognize, but it's rare. I have nothing to suggest in that regard. Perhaps someone will be able to suggest something.